Which definition of $\langle x_1, x_2, \ldots \rangle$ is correct?
Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ and let $\langle x_1, x_2,\ldots\rangle$ be the ideal of the ring $R$. Which definition of $\langle x_1, x_2, \ldots \rangle$ is correct?
$$
\langle x_1, x_2, \ldots \rangle=\left\{f_1x_1+f_2x_2+\ldots | f_i\in R\right\}
$$
or
$$
\langle x_1, x_2, \ldots \rangle=\left\{f_1x_{i_1}+f_2x_{i_2}+\ldots+f_nx_{i_n} |\ f_i\in R\quad n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}
$$
If both definitions are incorrect, please give the correct definition.

Some books also define $\langle x_1, x_2\cdots\rangle$ in the first way, but restricting $f_i=0$ for almost all $i$, where “almost all” means “does not hold on a set that is finite or $\varnothing$”.

In a general ring, we don't have any form of convergence, so infinite sums don't make sense. All sums have to be finite. So the second one is the correct one. Equivalently, you can describe it as $\{f_1x_1+...+f_nx_n: f_i\in R, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. (try to think why this is equivalent)
